# Bayesian updating and the limit of a relative frequency

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How does the Bayesian interpretation of probability handle a truly random world? Or, if the limit of a relative frequency is 0.75, how does Bayesian updating lead to that conclusion?

It seems the update of personal probability involves the discovery of a particular state of the world, given evidence, and that more evidence leads to a personal probability of 1, or does it not?

So I ask, can Bayesian updating converge to the limit of a relative frequency? If so, I would appreciate an example.

Answer (score 1):

I find the question a little confusing but I'll try to answer what I think you are asking. A *caveat*: this is just my interpretation. No proofs of any claims.

I assume by "truly random world" you are imagining an unfair coin with heads probabiiity $1/4$.

I assume your Bayesian observer would like to find out that probability.

She might begin with a prior that says it's $1/2$. Then if just before the $n$th toss she thought the probability was $p_n$ (so $p_0 = 0.5$) she could update to $p_{n+1}$ depending on the outcome of that toss. That would converge to $1/4$.

It would be less work for her just to channel Laplace and estimate $p$ as the proportion of heads so far.

In either case she could update her confidence in the prediction (as opposed to the prediction itself). That would converge to $1$.

Comment: your comment about confidence got me thinking. I think I will post another question to explain my thoughts better. I am partly unsure about what the hypotheses are here. Does one not need to state the alternative hypothesis of say, P(H) not 0.25, and if so, will my personal probability not once again converge to 1?

Comment: Mixing Bayesian and frequentist analyses is mathematically and philosophically difficult. Bayesians don't have hypotheses to reject. You might enjoy reading Andrew Gelman's blog. Search "null hypothesis" or "p value", https://andrewgelman.com/2018/11/21/bayesian-take-ballot-order-effects/